# Can any software analytically solve 2nd order, linear and separable PDEs?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, math-software, parabolic-pde, linear-pde

Is there any software that can solve 2nd order separable linear PDEs? (heat equation, wave equation, etc.)

For example, I'd like to get the analytic solution to the equation

$\partial_t B + G = R (\partial_{xx} B + \partial_{yy} B), \qquad B(x,y,t),G(t) = \text{known function of $t$},R=\text{constant}$

With Dirichlet BCs and zero initial condition: $B = 0 \in \partial \Omega, B(x,y,t=0) = 0$ on a domain $0 \le x \le L_x,0 \le x \le L_y, 0 \le t$.

---

I tried using mathematica, but it does not seem to provide any useful information:

[image]

---

My solution strategy without software is using Fourier series, I expect to see a convolution for the non-homogeneous part. Or using a Laplace transform. This is not a homework problem, I'm a researcher and often run into these equations and end up spending a lot of time deriving solutions every time I run into a new one.

I appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: It seems hard for a general-purpose program to figure that out, but it might be possible to write a custom command to automate what you usually do by hand.